# When to apply normalization principles during ER Diagram creation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, database-normalization

I'm new to databases.

In a database design process, I know that normalization is a step that occurs after the creation of the tables.

But is it to apply some of the normalization principles during ER Diagram creation?
If it is possible, it is a good practise or is it better to normalize after the tables' creation?

Comment: If you have created the tables, you would need to alter them significantly to normalise them. Normalisation is part of the design process and should be done before you start anything meaningful on the database.

Comment: It sounds like you are not making a distinct between logical and physical model design vs implementation - as JohnHC says, you would be doing all this before you touched the actual database server.

Comment: My pet peeve: people mistaking ER design for database design! You should really always start with conceptual model design, figure out your main THINGS and their relations. Then move to logical level, add keys and attributes and whatnot. ONLY then should you even consider opening a DBA tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which normal form does the ER Diagram guarantee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31023058/which-normal-form-does-the-er-diagram-guarantee)

Comment: Normalization is certain way to improve a design by replacing a table by smaller ones. It's just part of good design. Follow a plublished information modeling & relational design process. Chen Entity-Relationship Modeling imposes unnecessary restriction on designs and simultaneously underdetermines them. Object-Role Modeling & the others in the NIAM & FCO/IM family suffer less from that.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has worked with databases for decades, I have, for a long time, had a problem with the idea that you design a database wrongly first and then go through this theoretical process of normalisation to put it right.  This is all very long-winded and involves different teminology (ER modelling) and expensive diagramming tools.

I think it is important to understand the design principles: why do we store atomic fields in every column? why do we avoid repeating groups? why do we have primary and foreign keys? (and quite a few more).

It is also important to understand the system you are modelling and what the users need to do with it.  The best way to do this is to work with it.

So I go straight from discussions with the users to the create table statements in a plain text editor.  I have a checklist of what my tables should be like and how they should relate to one another, and my databases are always normalised.  My database designs are refactored and migrated on every iteration, and I don't have a bunch of fancy diagrams to fix every time.

This is implied in the Ruby on Rails books (by Sam Ruby and others) and is described in mine (which you can find on my profile if you're interested).  The free resource https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp is very good but I think the process of designing a good database is not very accessible there.

Comment: Huh, I'm glad that works for you but I personally couldn't live with that kind of process (straight from business needs to `create table`)! Also, regarding "expensive diagramming tools" my most successfull experiences are with post-its on a whiteboard ;)

Comment: I agree with this answer. Sometimes I scribble a diagram, but it's actually tables they show (so if I need a bridge table, it's in my diagram already). I also find the process of starting with a non-normalized database strange. I don't agree with w3schools being good, though.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner.  I scribble diagrams too, but they are small and temporary - just for communication.  I could say a lot more (and I have in several projects and in my book).  Knowledge, skill and discipline are necessary, absolutely, but the big up-front design wastes time and money.